# Display smiley button at right bottom on Android keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

I need to show smileys button by default when user input in my EditText.

Now keyboard for my EditText looks like:

[image]

Look at the right bottom, you will see done button.

In same time in sms app keyboard looks like:

[[image]

At the right bottom displays smiles button.

How do I display smile button in keyboard for my EditText?

Now I have next ExitText layout:

```
<EditText
  ... // some layout params             
  android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by adding following attributes in your `EditText`. Missing property in you code is `textShortMessage`. So you can try by adding same.

```
    android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. It looks strange, but I couldn't find solution in Internet during one hour.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add **imeOption** `textShortMessage`.

```
<EditText
  ... // some layout params             
  android:inputType="textShortMessage|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"/>
```